# New beginner for dynamically allocated Array. Why do I have segmentation fault here?

Tags: c

I use nested data structure for fibonacci, but I have a segmentation  fault 11.

```
void fib(int **fib_array, int n){

    fib_array = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fib_array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (i <= 1){
            fib_array[i][0] = i;
        }

        else{
            fib_array[i][0] = fib_array[i - 2][0] + fib_array[i - 1][0]; 
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* do not change this main function */
    int count = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int *fib_sequence;

    fib(&fib_sequence, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", fib_sequence[i]);
    }
    free(fib_sequence);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image, but textually, so that we can copy/paste it.

Comment: Did you try using `gdb` to determine where your fault occurs?

Answer (score 3):

you are being too complicated. You just need a single malloc

```
*fib_array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

and remove you second indexings `[0]` from everywhere

The consfusion comes from `**int`. This looks like a multi dim array. Its not - its declared `**` so that you can set the value in the caller. A simpler exampe will help

```
void Make42(int* v)
{
    *v = 42;
}

int main()
{
    int myv = 0;
    Make42(&myv);
    // now myv == 42
}
```

The `*` in the arg list is so that Make42 can 'reach out' and modify what was passed to it (myv in this case)

In your code the `**` on fib array is there for the same purpose.  you could have done (In know you werent allowed to by the test definition )

```
    int *fib(int n){
        int *fib_array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        ......
        return fib_array;
   }
```

and in main

```
fib_sequence = fib(count);
```

this makes it much clearer that you are really manipulating a simple array

Comment: but the type of fib_array is int**, so I m using nested data structure. I guess I have to malloc twice?

Comment: @Frank: fib_array is a pointer to another pointer. You use a single `malloc` as pm100 showed, and you assign the result to the pointer the `fib_array` pointer is pointing to. To do so, you need to dereference the `fib_array` pointer (note the asterisk in front of!).

Comment: @Frank really fib_array is an array pointer. Its declared `**` so that you can set the value in the caller. Its nothing to do with nesting. If instead fib was decalred to return the array it would just be `*`.

Answer (score 1):

pm100 is right, but a little short for answering to a beginner...

At first, you have passed a pointer to a pointer. If you want the original pointer to contain a value, you need to dereference the pointer to pointer:

```
*fib_array = ...
```

By assigning to the pointer only (as you did in your code), you do not modify the orignial pointer (`fib_sequence` in main) at all. And as you have not initialised it, it might point to *anywhere*, thus the segmentation fault when you try to print the values of it.

Then why an array of pointers to individually stored values? You can use a contiguous array of `int`s, which you get by

```
*fib_array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

OK, further usage won't be too nice (`(*fib_array)[i] = ...`), so I recommend a temporary variable instead:

```
int* fa = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
// now fill in the values comfortably:
fa[i] = ...;

// finally, assign the pointer to the target:
*fib_array = fa;
```

Side note: always check the result of `malloc`, it could be `NULL`:

```
fa = ...
if(fa)
   // assign values
else
    // appropriate error handling
```

In your concrete case, you could omit the else branch in your function and check your pointer outside within main function.

By the way, a simple return value would have made your live easier, too:

```
int* fib(int n)
{
    int* fib_array = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    // ...
    return fib_array;
}
```

Notice: no need for pointer to pointer... Usage:

```
int* fib_sequence = fib(count);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate